# How to use count distinct along multiple columns?

Tags: sql

Input:

```
id sem1 sem2 sem3 sem4 sem5 sem6 sem7
1    S   O     S    R  null null null
2    O   O     R    R    S  null null
```

Desired Output:

```
id O   R   S
1  1   1   2
2  2   2   1
```

Comment: You can use 'case when' condition

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports `APPLY/UNPIVOT` operator then use this

`CROSS APPLY` method

```
SELECT id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN val = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) O, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN val = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) R, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN val = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) S 
FROM   mytable 
       CROSS apply (VALUES (sem1), 
                           (sem2), 
                           (sem3), 
                           (sem4), 
                           (sem5), 
                           (sem6), 
                           (sem7)) cs(val) 
GROUP  BY id
```

- [***SQL FIDDLE DEMO***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/843bb/1)

`UNPIVOT` method

```
SELECT id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN val = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) O, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN val = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) R, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN val = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) S 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   mytable) a 
       UNPIVOT (val 
               FOR col IN ( sem1, 
                            sem2, 
                            sem3, 
                            sem4, 
                            sem5, 
                            sem6, 
                            sem7 )) upv 
GROUP  BY id
```

- [***SQL FIDDLE DEMO***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/843bb/2)

I personally prefer `CROSS APPLY` method over `UNPIVOT` since it is more readable. Performance wise both will be identical